# How to Replace HTML Using JavaScript Efficiently?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an HTML page where I want to replace occurrences of various words with links. For example:

```
<p>This is a test paragraph.</p>
```

I want to become:

```
 <p>This is a <a href="test.html">test</a> paragraph.</p>
```

Now, I know I can achieve that by using JavaScript as follows:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<a href='test.html'>test</a>"
```

And putting `<span id="test"></span>` around any word I want to change it to.

HOWEVER, There's approximately 100 words I want to do this for, and I don't want to have to give each word a unique id. Is there a faster/better way to do this that requires only a single id and then the js matches the word and replaces it with the relevant link?

Thanks for any help. **Please JavaScript answers only, no jQuery.**

Comment: Yoy can do replace ById with ByTagName or ByClassName. By doing this you can write from a <html> tag or CSS class

Comment: There is no easy or fast way of doing this. when you replace a word and go back, you might end up replacing items inside of other html tags which will break code.

Comment: If that's the case, would there be any noticeable slowdown if I had a script looking for 100 different id names? eg. my initial example. I can do it that way it's just inconvenient.

Comment: How would you like to map the elements to the correct content? Do you want to map the content.. because you need some kind of identifier on each element which you would like to set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I recommend giving an `id` attribute to `<p>This is a test paragraph.</p>`, or you can access it by `parentNode.getElementsByTagName('p')[n]` where `parentNode` could be `document` and `n` is a number, starting at `0` for the first Element. Check this out:

**HTML** modification

```
<p id='testId'>This is a test paragraph.</p>
```

Now for some **JavaScript**:

```
var doc, bod, E, T, makeLink;
var pre = onload; // change pre to anther var name if nesting onloads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

doc = document; bod = doc.body;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
makeLink = function(node, word, href){
  if(node.innerHTML){
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(word, "<a href='"+href+"'>"+word+'</a>');
  }
  return false;
}
makeLink(E('testId'), 'test', 'test.html');
/* without an `id` code could be
  makeLink(T('p')[0], 'test', 'test.html');
*/

}
```

Comment: I really love the code here. I tried it out on a blank page and it worked perfectly.When I inserted it into my site, however, it no longer worked (neither the E or T method). I'll keep troubleshooting though.

Comment: Use External JavaScript and put it in the `<head>`. Clear your cache. Did you forget the last `}`?

Comment: Already using an external script. Tried it in head and cleared the cache but still no luck. I'm wondering if one of my other scripts is interfering with it. I also tried changing the pre variable, just in case, but still nothing sadly.

Comment: Are you using anther load Event?

Comment: None of the scripts I have written use a load event. I do also have Lightbox (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) running though, which I suspect could be the issue (I'm running the jQuery-inclusive version).

Comment: Ok, put the external script tag for this script before your jQuery script tag then use the `makeLink` function inside `$(function(){/*here*/})` or `$(document).ready(function(){/*here*/})}`.

Comment: Ah, I found the issue! I do have another onload function in a different script used to generate a table of contents. Is there a way to get around this? Or is it a case of only one script will be able to work at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a function having one parameter: text to be replaced; set `this` of function to target element. Could create array or words to replace, iterate array of words using replacement function as callback

```js
// save original `.innerHTML` of element
var originalHTML = []; 
var elems = 0;

function re(text) {
  element = this;
  // if `text` is not empty string, not a number to reference 
  // index of `originalHTML`
  if (typeof text !== "number" && (typeof text === "string" && text.length)) {
    // save original `html`
    originalHTML.push(element.innerHTML); 
    // note `.textContent` is replaced here, not `.innerHTML`
    // to avoid replacing words within element tag or attributes
    element.innerHTML = element.textContent
      .replace(new RegExp("(" + text + ")", "g")
        // replace matched word with `a` element
        // add `replaced-` + `elems` `class` to `a` element
        , "<a href=" + text + ".html class=replaced-"+ elems +">$1</a>");
    ++elems;
  } else {
    // reset `element` `html` to `originalHTML`
    element.innerHTML = originalHTML[text];
  }      
}

re.call(document.querySelector("p"), "test");

setTimeout(function() {
  // reset to original html
  re.call(document.querySelector("p"), 0)
}, 5000)
```

```css
[class|='replaced'] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a test paragraph.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First give your element a class.

```
<p>This is a <a href="#" class="myClass">test</a> paragraph.</p>
```

Use a for loop to listen to ClassName

```
(function (){
var UI;
UI = {
    myLoad: function () {
        var myClass = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
        for (var i = 0; i < myClass.length; i++) {
            myClass[i].addEventListener('click', UI.myFunc, false);
        }
    },
    myFunc: function () {
        var myText = "My Test works";
        p1.innerHTML = myText;
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    UI.myLoad();
}
}())
```

Answer (score 0):

A fairly efficient way to do this would be to break your paragraph down into words, and map the result against a key index, before joining the strings back together.

In the code below, we split on word *boundries*, as indicated by the `/\b/` Regular Expression.

```
'Lorem ipsum sit amet, elit.'.split(/\b/)
```

becomes

```
["Lorem", " ", "ipsum", " ", "sit", " ", "amet", ", ", "elit", "."]
```

This assumes we're working with nothing but text in our paragraphs - no markup beforehand, or it will be lost.

Here's the basic example, which could be improved.

```js
function mapReplace (map, element) {
  var text = element.innerText,
      parts = text.split(/\b/);
      
  element.innerHTML = parts.map(function (part) {
   return map[part] || part;
  }).join('');
}

mapReplace({
  test: '<a href="test.html">test</a>'
}, document.getElementById('my-text'))
```

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="my-text">Lorem ipsum test dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur optio autem veniam in quisquam natus ducimus, quis, test doloremque officia deleniti odit blanditiis modi distinctio accusamus rem consequatur? Nulla, obcaecati, ipsa.</p>
```

Here's something a little more involved, which ignores case for matches, and interpolates the cased version.

```js
function wrapWords (words, element) {
  var text = element.innerText,
      parts = text.split(/\b/);

  element.innerHTML = parts.map(function (part) {
    var lower = part.toLowerCase(),
        output = part;

    if (words.hasOwnProperty(lower))
      output = words[lower].replace('{_}', part);

    return output;
  }).join('');
}

wrapWords({
  test: '<a href="test.html">{_}</a>',
  lorem: '<span>{_}</span>'
}, document.getElementById('my-text'))
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

a {
  color: red;
}

span {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="my-text">Lorem ipsum test dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur optio autem veniam in quisquam natus ducimus, quis, test doloremque officia deleniti odit blanditiis modi distinctio accusamus rem consequatur? Nulla, lorem <i>obcaecati</i>, ipsa.</p>
```

Whatever you do, don't use `.replace` / RegExp on raw HTML. If you ever see `innerHTML.replace` - run very far away.

Answer (score -2):

The fasted way to replace some html in a given html element is to use `innerHTML`.

```
var el = document.getElementById('elementId');
el.innerHTML = "<h1>JS generated content</h1>";
```

Obviously, you need some kind of mapping to the elements you would like to manipulate. You could do it in loop and check documents content, before manipulating.

Ok, here is an example which goes through all p - tags and replaces "google" with the google domain.

*this is only an example*

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerHTML.indexOf("google") > 0) {
    el.innerHTML.replace("google", "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Link to Google</a>)
  }
})
```

Instead of indexOf you could use regEx for example

```
if (/google/.test(el.innerHTML)) 
...
```

Comment: They clearly have that in the example. This is not what they are asking. The question is about a grepl-style insertion of DOM nodes.

Comment: @Oka Yes you are right, I added an example how to query and check elements.. so it is maybe clear